# How to get started with game development?

Tags: game-industry

I m a engineering student. I have intermediate knowledge of programming languages. I know how to program in C and C++, and i have no experience regarding graphics, sound or implementing physics in programs. But i am really interested in game development and want a little guidance on how to begin.

Comment: Hang out with me.

Comment: Find a tool or technology you like, and start making games. That's the best way to go. You learn along the way. Unity and XNA are popular choices.